# LinqToSql. Deadlock while updating a row. Parallel.For

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, parallel-processing

I have a problem. I'm trying to update the database base using parallel. Here is the code:

```
Parallel.For(rCnt, range.Rows.Count + 1, (jrCnt, loopState) =>
{
    var prcI = new Price(); // new 

    /*bla bla bla bla - bla bla - bla bla - bla */

    if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prcI.name)) && (prcI.prc != 0)) // process add or update
    {
        prcI.company = nameprice;
        prcI.date = datatimeselect.Text; 

        Accessor.AddProductUpdateProduct(prcI); // main func

            /*bla bla bla bla - bla bla - bla bla - bla bla - bla  */
    }
```

Here's the function code field to update:

```
public static bool AddProductUpdateProduct(Price price)
    {
        bool add = false;
        var db = new PriceDataContext();

        var matchedprod =
           db.Price.Single(x => x.name == price.name && x.date != price.date && x.company == price.company); // find match

        if (matchedprod != null) // match FOUnDE
        {
            if (matchedprod.prc != price.prc)
            {
                matchedprod.date = price.date;
                matchedprod.prc = price.prc;
            }
            else
            {
                matchedprod.date = price.date;
            }
            db.SubmitChanges(); // DEADLOCK is her!!!
        }
        /*bla - bla bla - bla bla - bla bla - bla bla - bla */
    }
```

When I create a record that all is well!

Thank you!

Comment: How many records are you updating/inserting here?

Comment: differently from 3,000 to 10,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a record count between 3000 and 10000 (comments) I would be looking at a solution here that used SqlBulkCopy to push the data into a staging table (i.e. a table that looks similar to the data you are manipulating, but not part of your core model). This is the most efficient way of getting a bulk set of data to the server (although you might also look at table valued parameters).

With the data at the server, I would then do either one update (inner join) and one insert (where not exists), or a single "upsert" (available in SQL Server 2008 and above).

This uses less CPU at the app-server, less network, and less database resources. Also, since only one SPID is involved in the insert/update there is no risk of deadlock.

Comment: Now try to use SqlBulkCopy. And the data are best kept in a datatable and then upload?

Comment: @Jin can you rephrase? I don't quite understand your comment. But yes: DataTable is one way to throw data at a SqlBulkCopy instance. But it doesn't need to be in DataTable before that.

Comment: I read about SqlBulkCopy. It only adds to the base? About the update did not find the information.

Comment: @Jin yes, which is why you insert into a STAGING table (as I mentioned), and **then** do the insert/update to to main tables.

Comment: Well I have not all data is taken from one place. I have another column with the data row that are added to another function. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I am Russian and my English I know is perfect. If you could give an example. I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: @Jin your English is better than my Russian! You should be able to construct a DataTable with all the columns you need..?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could be same problem I described in this question [Deadlock on SELECT/UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959501/deadlock-on-select-update). It is not the problem with linq to sql. The problem with linq to sql is that you can't easily perform select with updlock.

Comment: Yes, but without the isolation-level, the first select should be isolated and release any read-locks after the select; also, without "Serializable" it shouldn't be a key-range lock. Not quite the same scenario, IMO

Comment: I do not understand how to implement. I am with this problem for a week already struggling. Tell me, please.

Comment: Do you have to do it in parallel? Your problem occurs because multiple threads are dealing with data in same table. Performing operation on single thread is the easiest workaround. Otherwise I would write stored procedure that will use select with updlock and then add or update.