# SQL deadlock in select statement

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I am getting a SQL deadlock exception on select statements. WHY IS THAT SO?
Below is the XML report on deadlock:

```xml
<deadlock>
    <victim-list>
        <victimProcess id="process2f7b088"/>
    </victim-list>
    <process-list>
        <process id="process2f7b088" taskpriority="0" logused="5036" waitresource="KEY: 7:72057594042908672 (7c056d827cc3)" waittime="2497" ownerId="2702472" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-10-30T03:59:35.440" XDES="0x1878e987b0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="37" kpid="3268" status="suspended" spid="57" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2019-10-30T03:59:35.437" lastbatchcompleted="2019-10-30T03:59:35.443" lastattention="2019-10-30T03:59:35.433" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="BY3SCH106010521" hostpid="6692" loginname="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2702472" currentdb="7" currentdbname="IronMan" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671219744" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="IronMan.dbo.addRequestDependencyInternal" line="9" stmtstart="534" stmtend="964" sqlhandle="0x03000700a8429701375d7500d9aa000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  insert into @dependentIds          select distinct RequestId from RequestFileModificationList where IsActive = 1 and FilePath = ANY              (select FilePath from RequestFileModificationList where RequestId =@id    </frame>
                <frame procname="IronMan.dbo.addToFileModificationListTable" line="36" stmtstart="2220" stmtend="2360" sqlhandle="0x030007006f1ea300305d7500d9aa000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  execute addRequestDependencyInternal @id, @noOfRequestsAhead out;    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>  Proc [Database Id = 7 Object Id = 10690159]   </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process2ea8ca8" taskpriority="0" logused="5036" waitresource="KEY: 7:72057594042908672 (2713e7c4424f)" waittime="7493" ownerId="2703208" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-10-30T03:59:38.967" XDES="0x1879b447b0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="16" kpid="7152" status="suspended" spid="59" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1" lastbatchstarted="2019-10-30T03:59:38.967" lastbatchcompleted="2019-10-30T03:59:38.977" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.977" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="BY3SCH106010521" hostpid="6692" loginname="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2703208" currentdb="7" currentdbname="IronMan" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671219744" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="IronMan.dbo.addRequestDependencyInternal" line="9" stmtstart="534" stmtend="964" sqlhandle="0x03000700a8429701375d7500d9aa000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  insert into @dependentIds          select distinct RequestId from RequestFileModificationList where IsActive = 1 and FilePath = ANY              (select FilePath from RequestFileModificationList where RequestId =@id    </frame>
                <frame procname="IronMan.dbo.addToFileModificationListTable" line="36" stmtstart="2220" stmtend="2360" sqlhandle="0x030007006f1ea300305d7500d9aa000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  execute addRequestDependencyInternal @id, @noOfRequestsAhead out;    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>  Proc [Database Id = 7 Object Id = 10690159]   </inputbuf>
        </process>
    </process-list>
    <resource-list>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594042908672" dbid="7" objectname="IronMan.dbo.RequestFileModificationList" indexname="NonClusteredIndex-20190423-035837" id="lock187e052080" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594042908672">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process2ea8ca8" mode="X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process2f7b088" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594042908672" dbid="7" objectname="IronMan.dbo.RequestFileModificationList" indexname="NonClusteredIndex-20190423-035837" id="lock1860b3ea00" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594042908672">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process2f7b088" mode="X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process2ea8ca8" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
    </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Comment: There is non clustered index on isactive and requestid column

Comment: The selects are in the same transaction as an earlier statement that wrote to the table and still are retaining X locks from that. You can see this from `logused="5036"`

Comment: The deadlock resource seems on the NonClusteredIndex-20190423-035837 index so that you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099659/sql-server-2005-deadlock-with-nonclustered-index